# \includestandalone cannot compile \section or \subsection commands

Tags: sectioning, input, standalone

**Main.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\section{A}

\includestandalone{Subfile}
\end{document}
```

**Subfile.tex**

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\textbf{b}
\subsection{B}
\end{document}
```

**Results**

- Subfile.tex runs fine.
- Main.tex can find Subfile.tex
- Main.tex errors at first use of `\section` or `\subsection`.
- If `\input` is instead used, Main.tex works fine.
- Tested with shell escape, to no avail.

**Shell Escape**

Used arara for shell escape attempts:

```
%  arara: lmkclean  
%  arara: pdflatex: {   draft: yes, shell: yes }  
%  arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes, shell: yes }  
%  arara: lmkclean
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}
```

**Error Consistently Received**

> (./Subfile.tex
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> l.11 \subsection{B}

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out, it's not so hard to make a MWE...

Comment: If tried a lot of options and combinations, at the moment I would say it's a bug, but perhaps there is a 'weird' trick unknown to me.

Comment: The error message is missing a right parenthesis " ) ". I wonder if that is related. Overall, I think that this is a package bug as well.

Comment: You should write a mail to Martin Scharrer, the package author (he is also one of our moderators). Perhaps he has some clue for this

Comment: Oh yeah - already done. I asked him if this was recognized as a bug and sent him an email to this link : j

Comment: Hi, I will have a look at it and will try to make it work, but note that `standalone` was not written with section in mind but for diagrams and similar boxed content, so I would call it a limitation not a bug ;-)

Comment: The documentation definitely is written such that nesting complete files is not the direct intention, but it works so well! Seemingly better than input or subfiles. Perhaps it's more robust than you'd envisioned! :D

Answer (score 2):

The error happens because the subfile content is boxed and this causes issues with the sectioning commands. If you change `\includestandalone{Subfile}` with `\mbox{\input{Subfile}}` the same error occurs.

As `\includestandalone` is intended for stand-alone diagrams it boxes the content. Actually it adds an .tex-Driver to `\includegraphics` so that it can add TeX code as a 'graphic' as well. This adds the box.

There is not really a way around it. I recommend to use `\input` or `\include` instead. With the later you can use partial compiling using `\includeonly{..}` in the preamble.